# How to use regexp_replace in hive to remove strings

Tags: hive

I have a table as:

column1 -> 101#1,102#2,103#3,104#4

I am trying to remove strings (101#,102#,103#,104#). The expected output is

column2 -> 1,2,3,4

I am trying to do using regexp_replace

any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

It seems silly but, you have to break the string into an array, then transform (run a function) on each element, and finally concat the array back into a string.

```
select concat_ws( ',' , transform ( split('101#1,102#2,103#3,104#4',','), x -> regexp_replace( x, '.*#','' )))
```